# Listbox duplicates(repeats) on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I understand that this question is already posted and an answer has been given, but my case is different as I am populating multiple dropdown on a single method and so if I follow this link [After every postback dropdownlist items repeats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967331/after-every-postback-dropdownlist-items-repeats) it will only retain the items in the last dropdownlist as it would clear all the lists before it.

Below would be my code, I use this method as a filter for gridview.

```
private void BindDropDownList()
{
        PopulateDropDown(ddlgvsite, lblsite.Text);
        PopulateDropDown(ddlgvskill, lblskill.Text);
        PopulateDropDown(ddlgvshift, lblshift.Text);
        PopulateDropDown(ddlgvtm, lbltm.Text);
        PopulateDropDown(ddlgvgrpm, lblgrpm.Text);
        PopulateDropDown(ddlgvopsm, lblopsm.Text);
        PopulateDropDown(ddlgvltype, lblltype.Text);
}
private void PopulateDropDown(ListBox ddl, string columnName)
{
        ddl.DataSource = BindDropDown(columnName);
        ddl.DataTextField = columnName;
        ddl.DataValueField = columnName;
        ddl.DataBind();
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select", "0"));
}
private void setDropdownselectedItem(string selectedvalue, ListBox ddl)
{
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedvalue))
        {
            ddl.Items.FindByValue(selectedvalue).Selected = true;
        }
}
protected void DropDownChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox dropdown = (ListBox)sender;
        string selectedValue = dropdown.SelectedItem.Value;
        switch (dropdown.ID.ToLower())
        {
            case "ddlgvsite":
                ViewState["Site"] = selectedValue;
                break;
            case "ddlgvskill":
                ViewState["Skill"] = selectedValue;
                break;
            case "ddlgvshift":
                ViewState["Shift"] = selectedValue;
                break;
            case "ddlgvtm":
                ViewState["TM"] = selectedValue;
                break;
            case "ddlgvgrpm":
                ViewState["GrpM"] = selectedValue;
                break;
            case "ddlgvopsm":
                ViewState["OpsM"] = selectedValue;
                break;
            case "ddlgvltype":
                ViewState["Ltype"] = selectedValue;
                break;
        }
        this.BindGrid();
    }
private DataTable BindDropDown(string columnName)
    {
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strConnString);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT (" + columnName + ") FROM approved WHERE " + columnName + " IS NOT NULL", con);
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
```

So is there a way for me to avoid getting the lists repeated on postback? Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by Repopulate? Are there duplicate entries? If not then are you using an `IsPostBack` check?

Comment: Yes duplicate entries. Every time it postback the list entries get duplicated for example the original list of 1 2 3 becomes 1 2 3 1 2 3 after postback. It happens on all the listboxes

Comment: Then you are not checking for IsPostBack somewhere probably. Each time the data gets added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like DataBind isn't clearing the old values, so you could try:

```
ddl.Items.Clear();
```

at the start of PopulateDropDown

Comment: Can you also tell me how I can make multiple selection with this?

Comment: I'm not too sure about asp.net, but normally you'd set 'item.selected = true' for each item, rather than set a single 'selecteditem' property. I'm not sure if asp.net supports it, so I found this article that might help: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18063/Multi-select-Dropdown-list-in-ASP-NET